# Transforming a .txt file into two strings in java

Tags: java, string, text-files

If you have a text file called "login.txt" - in the same folder as the executable jar - that contains `ID:username Password:password` which is the best way to transform the ID and Password contents into two strings so you can replace them in something like: `api.login("username", "password");` P.S. no spaces in username and password, my bad.

Edit: At  `api.login("username", "password");` the username and password whould be what I had originally and I wanted to transform into strings like  `api.login(ID, Password);` from the file

Comment: `String#split`? BUT, you'd need to know if `username` or `password` could contain spaces

Comment: Ummm theres probably a bunch of ways to do so, you can use the String.equals() class, you can utilize a HashMap, you can use a multi dimensional array, regexes, It really depends on weapon of choice.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: @MadProgrammer no spaces

Comment: Apologies in advance - [couldn't resist](https://xkcd.com/208/).

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate: the conditions:

- the format is `ID:username Password:password`
- `ID` is a static string
- `Password` is a static string
- `username` **never** contains spaces.

You can then extract the data with the simple Regex:

```
ID:(?<username>[^\s]++)\s++Password:(?<password>.*+)
```

For example:

```
public User extractCredentials(final String data) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ID:(?<username>[^\\s]++)\\s++Password:(?<password>.*+)");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid data format");
    }
    return new User(matcher.group("username"), matcher.group("password"));
}

public class User {
    private final String name;
    private final String password;

    public User(String name, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    //getter


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User{name='%s', password='%s'}", name, password);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.out.println(extractCredentials("ID:username Password:password"));

User{name='username', password='password'}
```